# JobParameters cannot be found in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, parameter-passing, batch-processing

I need your help plizz!!

i have a spring batch app and i need to pass job parameters to my quartz job.
Here is my JobLauncher in which i want to pass each line of list as job parameters :

```
@Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            JdbcTemplate Jd = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
            List<QuartzParameters> list=null;
            list=Jd.query("select * from FLUX_INFO",new QuartzParametersMapper());
        
            for (QuartzParameters i : list) {
                Job job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);
                JobParametersBuilder JP = new JobParametersBuilder();
                JP.addString("PAYS", i.getPAYS());
                JP.addString("CRON", i.getCRON());
                JP.addString("CLASSAPP",i.getCLASSAPP());
                JobParameters paramJobParameters=JP.toJobParameters();
            
               JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, paramJobParameters);
          
                 log.info("{}_{} was completed successfully", job.getName(), jobExecution.getId());
            } } catch (Exception e) {
                 log.error("Encountered job execution exception!");
        }}}
```

And here is my batch config class :

```
@Value("#{jobParameters[CLASSAPP]}")
    private String ClassApp;
 @Scope("step")
     @Bean
     public JdbcCursorItemReader<FichierEclate> readerDB(){
      JdbcCursorItemReader<FichierEclate> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<FichierEclate>();
      reader.setDataSource(ds);
      reader.setSql(query(ClassApp));
      reader.setRowMapper(new FichierEclateRowMapper());
      return reader;
     }
```

i am also using another parameter in Quartz config :

```
@Value("#{jobParameters[CRON]}")
    private  String CRON_EXPRESSION;
    @StepScope
        @Bean
        public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
            JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
            factory.setJobClass(QuartzJobLauncher.class);
            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("jobName", "JobFinal");
            map.put("jobLauncher", jobLauncher);
            map.put("jobLocator", jobLocator);
            map.put("CRON_EXPRESSION", CRON_EXPRESSION );
            factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
            factory.setGroup("etl_group");
            factory.setName("etl_job");
            return factory;}
```

I am also using the job parameter in the processor class :

```
@Value("#{jobParameters[CLASSAPP]}")
    private String ClassApp;
@Scope("step")
    @Override
    public TdfFile process(FichierEclate item) throws Exception {
    
        //some code and use the **CLASSAPP** variable }
```

i tried to use @StepScope But same problem !! i get this :

```
 Error creating bean with name 'batchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ClassApp'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Here is QuartzConfiguration class :

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {
    
    @Value("#{jobParameters[CRON]}")
    private  String CRON_EXPRESSION;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private JobLocator jobLocator;
    
 
    public QuartzConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="step", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(QuartzJobLauncher.class);
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("jobName", "JobFinal");
        map.put("jobLauncher", jobLauncher);
        map.put("jobLocator", jobLocator);
        map.put("CRON_EXPRESSION", CRON_EXPRESSION );
        factory.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        factory.setGroup("etl_group");
        factory.setName("etl_job");
        return factory;
    }
      
    // Job is scheduled after every 3 minutes

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setName("cron_trigger");
        stFactory.setGroup("cron_group");
        stFactory.setCronExpression(CRON_EXPRESSION);
      //  stFactory.getJobDataMap().get(app);
        return stFactory;     
    }
 
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return scheduler;
    }}
```

And here is the jobLauncher class :

```
public class QuartzJobLauncher extends QuartzJobBean {
     
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzJobLauncher.class);
    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;
    
    private String jobName;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobLocator jobLocator;
     
    public String getJobName() {
        return jobName;
    }
    public void setJobName(String jobName) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
    }
    public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }
    public JobLocator getJobLocator() {
        return jobLocator;
    }
    public void setJobLocator(JobLocator jobLocator) {
        this.jobLocator = jobLocator;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            JdbcTemplate Jd = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
            List<QuartzParameters> list=null;
            list=Jd.query("select * from FLUX_INFO",new QuartzParametersMapper());
        
            for (QuartzParameters i : list) {
                Job job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);
                JobParametersBuilder JP = new JobParametersBuilder();
                JP.addString("PAYS", i.getPAYS());
                JP.addString("CRON", i.getCRON());
                JP.addString("CLASSAPP",i.getCLASSAPP());
                JobParameters paramJobParameters=JP.toJobParameters(); 
            
              final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, paramJobParameters);
          
                 log.info("{}_{} was completed successfully", job.getName(), jobExecution.getId());
             }} catch (Exception e) {
                 log.error("Encountered job execution exception!");
        }}}
```

I tried to add **@Scope(value="step", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)** on **classes** directly or on **Beans** !! Both ways did not work !
Did anyone try a solution to solve this pliz ?!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are injecting the job parameter in a field of your class, then `@Scope("step")` should be placed on the class itself, something like:

```
@Component
@Scope("step")
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<FichierEclate, TdfFile> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters[CLASSAPP]}")
    private String ClassApp;

    @Override
    public TdfFile process(FichierEclate item) throws Exception {
   
        //some code and use the **CLASSAPP** variable 
    }
}
```

The same thing should be done for other classes where you want to inject `jobParameters[CRON]` and `jobParameters[CLASSAPP]`.

Comment: thank you so much for help :) Now the problem is with the quartz config class that produces this erreor " Error creating bean with name 'quartzConfiguration': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean" when i put @scope("step") on the name of the class!!

Comment: Please edit the description of your question with your latest changes and share the whole class and not only parts of it. Otherwise please share a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: I added quartzConfiguration class and the jobLauncher class when i declare jobParameters and added a detail at the end

Comment: `QuartzConfiguration` class should be step-scoped as well since it injects a job parameter in the `@Value("#{jobParameters[CRON]}") private  String CRON_EXPRESSION;`. You should avoid using field injection in configuration classes and pass job parameters as parameters in bean methods. That said, the cron expression is rather a parameter of the schedule, not the job itself. So it should not be passed as a job parameter IMO.